# Create action running on trashed_post hook to modify post_meta value

Tags: custom-post-types, hooks, post-meta, actions, trash

I have a custom post type that always do math operation to its post_meta and other custom post type post_meta.

For example:

- post-type 1 = **cpt_product_order**
- post-type 1 post_meta = **cpt_pm_product_order**
- post-type 2 = **cpt_product**
- post-type 2 post_meta = **cpt_pm_product_stock**

There's a cpt_product with cpt_pm_product_stock = 100, frontend operation enable specific user made order by inserting new cpt_product with post_meta cpt_product_order of 10 will substract cpt_pm_product_stock to 90

100 **cpt_pm_product_stock** - 10 **cpt_product_order** = 90 **cpt_pm_product_stock**

cancelling order will delete/trash the cpt_product and cpt_product_order, and cpt_pm_product_stock should back to 100.

Which action hook should used for this operation? Is it trashed_post?

I didn't find any answer on codex, http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/trashed_post is empty

Thanks in advance for an answer. ;)

Comment: Please use the code styling and links - we'll approve your edit in mins. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`wp_trash_post` and `trashed_post` - from source:

```
function wp_trash_post($post_id = 0) {
    if ( !EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS )
        return wp_delete_post($post_id, true);

    if ( !$post = wp_get_single_post($post_id, ARRAY_A) )
        return $post;

    if ( $post['post_status'] == 'trash' )
        return false;

    do_action('wp_trash_post', $post_id);

    add_post_meta($post_id,'_wp_trash_meta_status', $post['post_status']);
    add_post_meta($post_id,'_wp_trash_meta_time', time());

    $post['post_status'] = 'trash';
    wp_insert_post($post);

    wp_trash_post_comments($post_id);

    do_action('trashed_post', $post_id);

    return $post;
}
```

Comment: Is add_action to this wp_trash_post() hook, is it work when we use wp_delete_post() ?

Comment: No, you'll also need to use `before_delete_post` (pre) or `deleted_post` (post) to listen out for deletions.

Comment: wp_trash_post only seems to work on posts, not on pages or CPTs

Answer (score 0):

`before_delete_post` or `wp_trash_post`.

Both hooks are triggered before a post is deleted or trashed. You can use one of these hooks to perform the necessary operations when a post of `cpt_product_order` is deleted or trashed.

```
add_action('before_delete_post', 'restore_stock_on_order_cancellation');

function restore_stock_on_order_cancellation($post_id) {
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

    // Check if the post being deleted is of the 'cpt_product_order' type
    if ($post_type === 'cpt_product_order') {
        // Get the order amount from post meta
        $order = get_post_meta($post_id, 'cpt_pm_product_order', true);

        // Get the product ID from post meta
        $product_id = get_post_meta($post_id, 'cpt_pm_product_id', true);

        // Increase the stock of the related product
        $current_stock = get_post_meta($product_id, 'cpt_pm_product_stock', true);
        $new_stock = $current_stock + $order;
        update_post_meta($product_id, 'cpt_pm_product_stock', $new_stock);
    }
}
```